# Can multiple HTML elements receive focus at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html, focus

I'm a coding a JavaScript reporting component, that requires multiple LI's i.e. lists to be selected collectively as a bunch with visual feedback.

I'm thinking of adapting the `onfocus` event. Is it possible for multiple HTML elements to receive focus at the same time?

Not inputs, but DIVs, so I don't need the cursor. I just want several DIVs to be "selected" separately from others, colored differently to simulate multiple item selection.

Comment: why you want do this with multiple onfocus!? simply call all you needs after a single onfocus event

Comment: he wants the cursor blinking in all 10 text inputs, duh </sarcasm>

Comment: Not necessarily inputs, but DIVs, so I don't need the cursor.

Comment: Only saw your comment now. How can a "div" focus? onfocus is not an event of div http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp

Comment: @Neb - IN HTML 4, you can validly assign a focus event listener to a div via javascript. In HTML5, onfocus is a valid event attribute for a div. Similarly, add attribute tabIndex="0" to add the div to the tab order.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

No, you can only *focus* on one element at a time.

Comment: Yeah i had to edit it before any other answers were posted that way no suspicions of plagiarism will arise ;)

Comment: I wonder is there any documentation about proving this?

Answer (score 5):

As the other answers state, only 1 element can have focus at any given time. 
What you could do instead is add a class to each of the 'selected' elements.

A simple example (using yui) would be:

```
 <style type="text/css">
     .selectedItem{border: 2px dashed #c0ffee;}
 </style>
...
<ul class='listContainer'>
     <li> ... </li>
     <li> ... </li>
     <li> ... </li>
</ul>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
     Y.one('.listContainer').delegate(
         'click', 
         function(e){ e.currentTarget.toggleClass('selectedItem');}, 
         'li'
     );
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

No. The whole point of focus is that one element is selected(as in a "spotlight" for it). But if you want double writing text boxes then use this

```
<input type="text" name="firstbox" onchange="firstbox.value = secondbox.value; return true;">
<input type="text" name="secondbox">
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe so.  If two text fields had focus at the same time, which would receive the input?  You can "simulate" this (one field has focus and code "duplicates" the values), but only one item at a time can be "the focus".

Answer (score 1):

No.
An extensive answer from an accessibility point of view is that the
Focus enables screen readers to identify and announce dynamic website features, conveying to users what is happening on the screen. If a webpage were to permit more than one focus at a time, it could disrupt the persistence of keyboard navigation and voice-over behavior, and your application would not comply with accessibility standards.