# Check regex validation on submit and focus all input fields if empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check the regex validation when I click on the button. It works fine when the button type is submit, but it does not redirect to another page where I have linked the button - however when I change its type to button it redirects to the other page normally and does not check the regex validation. I am also checking if all the input fields are filled, and focusing any empty fields. But I guess something is wrong with the code.

[Demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/preetisingh/41kw09gw/)

HTML CODE:

```
<form action="" method="POST" role="form" class="payment_form">
    <div class="contact_details">
        <div class="payment_details">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="input_name" id="fullName" pattern="^([a-zA-Z]+\s)*[a-zA-Z]+$" title="Type only characters" name="fullName"  placeholder="FULL NAME" required/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <input type="email" class="input_name" id="email" title="Eg: some@mail.com" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS" required/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="input_name" id="mobileNumber" maxlength="10" pattern="^(\+\d{1,3}[- ]?)?\d{10}$" title="Enter 10 digit Valid Mobile Number" name="mobileNumber" placeholder="MOBILE NUMBER" required/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <a href="thankyou.html" title=""><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pay_btn" >Continue</button></a>   
 </form>
```

JS:

```
$('.pay_btn').click(function(e){
   $(":input").each(function() {
      if($(this).val() === "")
      $(this).css('border-color', '#ff0000');
   });
});
```

Comment: should not focus all in input field at the same time, Its not possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017011/can-multiple-html-elements-receive-focus-at-the-same-time

Comment: @nisar Ok but when I change the button type to submit it checks the regex validation but does not redirects to other page when all the fields are filled it just becomes blanks. Any idea idea why this is happening

Comment: https://fiddle.jshell.net/dLrnq3nd/ ...as urvashi said correctly...

Comment: Any answer for this error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed) it is showing this error in console when page is redirecting

Comment: where are you trying these code? @Preety Angel

Comment: I too run in localhost , It redirect corrctly, I am sure that code is 100% correct.you have some other issues or I ll post the folder. What I have tired.. @Preety Angel server I m using nodejs

Comment: @nisar Yeah please post the folder

Comment: add mail id in your profile.

Comment: It worked nisar. I just removed the POST method and the page is getting loaded now. As @reddy said I haven't integrated with the server side scripting so it was showing error. Now its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to check the regex validation when I click on the button. It working fine, when the button type is submit but it does not redirect to another page where i have linked the button,

Whats happening here is, You click on the button who's type is submit, And this button will try to submit the form. So `your validation will work on form submit`. Since you don't have any url mentioned in the `action=""` attribute of your form, Your page doesn't know where to go. So solution is **add the URL into this `action` attribute**

```
<form action="thankyou.html" method="POST" role="form" class="payment_form">
```

> but when I am changing the button type to button it redirects to other page normally and does not check the regex validation.

The reason for this is `once you remove the button type submit it has nothing to do with the form anymore`. Its just a plain button. But you have wrapped this button inside a anchor tag which has a `href` set. So this is as good as a page redirect by clicking a link, So the form is not submitted at all. Hence your validation keeps quiet. As it works only while form is submitted.

Comment: I have used it in action the url is changing but the design is not getting rendered

Comment: @PreetyAngel  what do you mean by `design is not getting rendered` . Can you specify what is breaking

Comment: The Page is not getting loaded in the url it is showing the page name like http://localhost:3000/thankyou.html but the screen is complete white. Whatever layout I have developed for thankyou page is not getting loaded the screen is white and when i inspect there is nothing inside the body and when i refresh the page it shows an alert saying that confirm form resubmission.

Comment: Any answer for this error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed) it is showing this error in console when page is redirecting

Comment: @PreetyAngel There must be some issue in the server code. What is your server code language?

Comment: Actually I have to integrate in ruby. But currently I am not doing anything it's just plain html,css,javascript or jquery. Is it because of that?? I havent integrated ?

Comment: @PreetyAngel Yes,  Since it will post to a server and if you dont have one then you get the error...

Comment: Its working now. The problem was method="POST" as I have not integrated with the server it was not showing anything. I have removed the  method. It worked now, and page is also getting loaded.

Comment: Nice!!, Glad you got it fixed. @PreetyAngel

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove anchor tag from submit button and write the name of html page in action ,this will work fine for page redirection when form is correctly field .For the one field focus at a time you have to change your logic out there .

Comment: I tried the url is getting changed, but the page is not geting loaded I mean the screen is plain white.

Comment: Please check the url and compare it,i mean does the file actually exists at the new url(which got changed after submit)

Comment: Urvashi Its not showing anything inside the body when I inspect in the browser but the file is there.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed) it is showing this error in console when page is redirecting

Answer (score 1):

@Preety Angel , Provide the html file name in the `action` attribute of form tag `<form action="thankyou.html">` like below,

```
<form action="thankyou.html" method="POST" role="form" class="payment_form">
.......
</form>
```