# Is there any possible way to have multi layer view in ionic?

Tags: html, user-interface, ionic2

Is there any possible way to show or to have multi layer view. I mean  `UI` component in are independently but both of them could be focused?
**for example :**
showing text box over an image, and person could  entering text in text box, without closing input box could replace or dragging image under the box.

**Update**
I used something like this but I used the fallowing code but it shows error

```
<ion-fab top>   
     <ion-item>
       <ion-label fixed>Username</ion-label>
     <ion-input type="text" value=""></ion-input> 
  </ion-item>
```

[image]

Comment: See that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017011/can-multiple-html-elements-receive-focus-at-the-same-time

Comment: I used <ion-fab> tag but looking for better solution.