# Keep html highlight when clicking on an input field?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

How can I retain highlights on html text when I click an input field in **React**?

[**Sample Sandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-lamport-20olu)

Comment: No, you can't https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017011/can-multiple-html-elements-receive-focus-at-the-same-time

Comment: **[placholder="the highlight goes away"]:focus{
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff
}** put this line of code into your `Sandbox` **`styles.css`** file and It will work as you want.