# Can't type in input text when input color picker is showing up

Tags: javascript, html, input, colors

I'm trying to open the picker the same time someone types something on the textbox. But what happens is when it opens, I can't type on the textbox. Is this the right way to do it? Or is there a better approach?

```js
function openPicker(e) {
  e.nextElementSibling.click();
}
```

```css
.color-picker-container {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: transparent;
    flex-grow: 1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    max-height: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.color-picker-text-field {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    color: #4e4e4e;
    max-height: 15px;
    padding: 4px;
    font-size: 12px;
    min-width: 0px;
    margin: 0px !important;
    border: inherit !important;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #dadada;
    width: 50%;
}

.color-picker-field {
    margin: 0px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    max-height: 15px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 50px;
    border-left: solid 3px #f0ecf3;
}
```

```html
<div class="color-picker-container " style="">
      <input type="text" class="color-picker-text-field" value="#ffffff" onclick="openPicker(this);">
      <input class="color-picker-field primary-color-picker" type="color" value="#ffffff">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't interact with the `input` if some other input is in the `focus` state. So remove the below line because either you can type in the first `input` or you can select the color on the second input at the same time. If `color` input is in the `focus` state (when you click on the `first` input) then you can't type because it is expecting input from user.

[Can multiple HTML elements receive focus at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017011/can-multiple-html-elements-receive-focus-at-the-same-time)

```
e.nextElementSibling.click();
```

When the above code gets executed then the second(color) input will be in `focus` state, which restricts the other input to be in the focus state until user input the value or input loses its `focus`.

> There can only one element in the `focus` state.
>
> : the focus is when an element is able to accept input - the cursor in an input box or a link that has been tabbed to.

**If you want to set the default value of the `color` input, set it using `value`**

```html
<div class="color-picker-container " style="">
  <input class="color-picker-field primary-color-picker" type="color" value="#19d763">
</div>
```

Comment: I can see that now. Thanks for the insight, do you see any other approach that is possible?

Comment: approach for what @kimlianlopez

Comment: what do you want to do with the text input and a color input?

Comment: Well the initial goal was to set a default for the color input to have default value of hex, but the default is rgb. So that's why I did another input that could do that

Comment: If you need to set the default color of `color` input, You've already done it with `value`. where `value="#ffffff"`;

Comment: @kimlianlopez required code for default color