# CSS: apply :focus style to unfocused element?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a fieldset that needs to imitate the appearance of components from a library, but I can't directly copy-paste its styling into the css for that div, since if the library theme gets changed then that copy-pasted css won't match with the other components. I was more or less doing this by applying the css classes used by that library (e.g. `library-class`) to non-library elements like so (I'm using react):

```
return (
<fieldset className="library-class">
    <input/>
    <input/>
    <input/>
</fieldset>);
```

My issue is that the library applies this box shadow to input elements in focus, but I need my whole fieldset to show that box shadow - rather than the inputs inside - when any element inside is focused. The browser debug css looks like this:

```
library-class:focus{
    box-shadow: #c1c1c1 0 0 1px;
}
```

Is there a way to forcefully apply the :focus pseudo class to my whole fieldset?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can multiple HTML elements receive focus at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017011/can-multiple-html-elements-receive-focus-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:focus-within` pseudo-class:

```css
.library-class:focus-within {
  box-shadow: #f90 0 0 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="library-class">
  <input/>
  <input/>
  <input/>
</fieldset>
```

References:

- [`:focus-within`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't edit the library css itself either.