# Focus an element of a list (search result) while continue writing in an input

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I have a custom searcher in my React js app, and I need to focus an element of the search results (so I can navigate with arrow keys) leaving the input focused as well so I can continue writing.

thanks

Comment: can two elements truly have focus?? just handle up/down arrow keys to move the "highlighted" (use elements class maybe) element of the search results

Comment: HI @Bravo, thanks for answering. Yes! I thought about that alternative, but how could I move down also with the scroll (assuming I have for example 10 results and they don't fit in their father component)? I cant resolve that

Comment: You're probably doing it wrong - but the code you've shown doesn't make it easy to help you

Comment: Maybe this link could help you since your question is similar to this :D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017011/can-multiple-html-elements-receive-focus-at-the-same-time

Comment: HeadlessUI has great accessibility features. This video explaining their new command palette sounds like what you want: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-jix4KyxLuQ

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to simulate what you want. Add keydown event listeners to input. And then see what is pressed. If it is allowed symbol then add this symbol to inputs actual value. If it is arrow, then add a specific class to need search item (f.e. `focused-search-item`) and add little another style rules. And when you press `enter` then get the "focused" element and simulate click event on it